# UserPackageLicense in beta packages

Tags: apex, managed-package, licenses

Our managed package checks for UserPackageLicenses based on which we allow certain users to be added to a custom object in the app. If the user has a license, it can be part of the custom object.

The problem is that when we create a beta package to test this out, we can't assign licenses since beta package gets installed as free and the allowed license is -1. Hence we are not able to add the user to custom object.

Is there a way we can achieve this?

Comment: The user should automatically have access to the object, because every user in the org should already have access. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The user has access to the custom object but we have custom logic in the VF page where we check that the user has the license as well before adding to that object. This works perfectly in production with licenses assigned to user however the logic would have to change for beta packages I believe. Is there a way we can differentiate between beta vs release packages?

Comment: How are you checking for licensing? You should be using UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed()...

Comment: We have to check licensing fir multiple users not just the current user. So we query the userpackagelicense object for the user ids